NextJS Leaflet problem with zoom and position tracking
I've been working on my problem for a while but I can't seem to solve it:
I am a beginner on NextJs, I am working on a project of an interactive map for a game, currently my map works correctly, I can put markers etc.. Now I want to be able to track the user's zoom and position on the map in real time with "CameraPositionTracker" component.
I want to have access to the zoom and position values from the parent component (‘Map’), so I've created 2 State (zoomLevel and cameraPosition)
Map component :
'use client';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import L, { CRS } from 'leaflet';

import Mark from '@/components/map/Mark';

import CameraPositionTracker from '@/components/map/CameraPositionTracker';
import ViewBounds from '@/components/map/ViewBounds';

const mapMaxResolution = 1.00000000;
const mapMinZoom = 3;
const mapMaxZoom = 5;
const CustomCRS = {
  ...CRS.Simple,
  transformation: new L.Transformation(1, 0.00000000, -1, 0.00000000),
  scale: (zoom) => Math.pow(2, zoom) / (Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom) * mapMaxResolution), // mapMaxZoom = 4, mapMaxResolution = 1.0
  zoom: (scale) => Math.log(scale * ((Math.pow(2, mapMaxZoom) * mapMaxResolution))) / Math.LN2,
}


const Map = ({ markers }) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const mapExtent = [0.00000000, -7500.00000000, 7500.00000000, 0.00000000]; // xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
  
  const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel]  = useState(3)
  const [cameraPosition, setCameraPosition] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {    
    console.log("zoom : ",zoomLevel);
  }, [zoomLevel]);  

  return (
    <div className="">
      <MapContainer
        crs={CustomCRS}
        center={[0, 0]}
        minZoom={mapMinZoom}
        maxZoom={mapMaxZoom}
        zoomControl={false}
        style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', position: 'relative'}}
        // whenCreated={(map) => setMap(map)}
        // whenCreated={(map) => (mapRef.current = map)}
        attributionControl={false}
        // onZoomEnd={() => setZoomLevel()}
      >
        <TileLayer
          url="http://localhost:3000/images/tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
          tileSize={256}
          minZoom={mapMinZoom}
          maxZoom={mapMaxZoom}
          noWrap={true}
          tms={false}
          maxBounds={[
            [-7500, 0],
            [0, 7500],
          ]}
          maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
          bounds={[
            {lat: 0, lng: 7500}, // Bottom-left (ymin, xmin)
            {lat: -7500, lng: 0}, // Top-right (ymax, xmax)
          ]}
        />

        <CameraPositionTracker setZoomLevel={setZoomLevel} setCameraPosition={setCameraPosition}/>
        <ViewBounds mapExtent={mapExtent} />

        {markers.filter((marker) => marker.isDisplayed).map(marker => (
          <Mark key={marker.id} position={[marker.coordinates.lat,marker.coordinates.long]} data={marker}/>
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;

CameraPositionTracker component :
const CameraPositionTracker = ({ setZoomLevel, setCameraPosition }) => {
    // const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(3); // initial zoom level provided for MapContainer
    
    const map = useMap();

    const onZoom = () => {
        const currentZoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        setZoomLevel(currentZoomLevel);
    }

    const onMove = () => {
        const currentCameraPosition = map.getCenter(); 
        setCameraPosition({ lat: currentCameraPosition.lat, lng: currentCameraPosition.lng });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
               
        map.on("moveend", onMove);
        map.on("zoomend", onZoom);

        return () => {
            map.off('zoomend', onZoom);
            map.off("moveend", onMove);
        }
    }, []);
    
    return null
}

With this code I can track the zoom when I zoom in on the map, so far so good.
The code below only works when I declare the state directly in the ‘CameraPositionTracker’ component, but when I use the state of the parent component, the map zoom is updated each time to the initial state of my zoom. So in the end my ‘zoomLevel’ state remains the same and never changes, and visually it creates a zoom-in then zoom-out effect.
Finally I have the impression that my state is synchronised with the map but in a completely buggy way, even though I don't want it to be synchronised with it. In the attributes of my map I don't have ‘zoom={zoomLevel}’ which would normally synchronise. Default zoom is 3

When I do the same thing in the component but for the position, it creates an infinite loop and makes everything crash.
I hope I've made my problem as clear as possible, and thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

can you create a codesandbox example?

sure sandbox code
don't pay attention to nextjs errors

thanks for the codesandbox. the issue here is exactly as you described it, the state udpate in CameraPositionTracker will re-render the Map, thus resetting the zoom to the initial value. can I know why do you need the state in the parent component? and why not go with the solution you have? to use the state in the child component

it's true that when I think about it I won't need it because I thought I would need it to place the zoom or the position in a specific place, but in the end I didn't. Thanks for your help.
